# Java .add(value) with lists

Tags: java

Basically I've got an input string, my test string is '5 + 4' and I want to check character by character to create a list in the form [5,+,4], ie white spaces are ignored. Also, if my test string was '567+5-1' it would output [567,+,5,-,1] by concatenating the numbers together. Unfortunately, it won't let me do `.add(inputChar)` to my `returnValue`, saying symbol not found... any ideas?

```
import java.util.*;

public class CharacterArray {
    public List<String> splitToChar(String s) {
        List<String> returnValue = new LinkedList<String>();
        char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
        System.out.println(chars);
        int currentNumber;
        for (char inputChar : chars) {
            if (Character.isDigit(inputChar) == true) {
                currentNumber += inputChar;
            } else if (inputChar == '.') {
                currentNumber += inputChar;
            } else if (inputChar == '+') {
                returnValue.add(inputChar);
            } else if (inputChar == '-') {
                returnValue.add(inputChar);
            } else if (inputChar == '/') {
                returnValue.add(inputChar);
            } else if (inputChar == '*') {
                returnValue.add(inputChar);
            } else if (inputChar == '(') {
                returnValue.add(inputChar);
            } else if (inputChar == ')') {
                returnValue.add(inputChar);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Incorrect input symbol");
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're guaranteed whitespace, why not just split on whitespace? Also, you could use a switch. And check all the conditions at once, since they all do precisely the same thing. Also, pretty sure `currentNumber += inputChar` isn't what you want.

Comment: *"I want to check character by character"*  What is the ultimate purpose of doing so?  Is this an academic exercise, homework?  If not, note that the ECMAScript (JavaScript) version of the [`ScriptEngine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html) can *evaluate* string expressions.

Comment: I'm not guarenteed whitespace, I wan't it to accept either. Thanks

Comment: BTW: Are you missing the `[homework]` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.*;

public class CharacterArray {
    public List<String> splitToChar(String s) {
        List<String> returnValue = new LinkedList<String>();
        char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
        System.out.println(chars);
        String currentNumber = "";
        for (char inputChar : chars) {
            if (Character.isDigit(inputChar) == true) {
                currentNumber += inputChar;
            } else if (inputChar == '.' ||
                    inputChar == '+' ||
                    inputChar == '-' ||
                    inputChar == '/' ||
                    inputChar == '*' ||
                    inputChar == '(' ||
                    inputChar == ')') {
                if (currentNumber.length() > 0){
                    returnValue.add(currentNumber);
                }
                currentNumber = "";
                returnValue.add(""+inputChar);
            }  else {
                System.out.println("Incorrect input symbol");
            }
        }
        if (currentNumber.length() > 0){
            returnValue.add(currentNumber);
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

By the way, your `currentNumber` should be a String

Comment: This will drop the last string if its a number.

Comment: Ah, yes, missed that.. After the for loop, check the length of currentNumber. If it's > 0, add it to the list..

Comment: You should really check before each symbol as well. e.g. `5 * -3`

Answer (score 1):

how about `.add(String.valueOf(inputChar))`  ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a `char` to a `List<String>`  perhaps what you are trying to do is like

```
String currentNumber = "";
for (char inputChar : chars) {
    if (Character.isDigit(inputChar) || inputChar == '.') {
        currentNumber += inputChar;
    } else if ("+-/*()".indexOf(inputChar) >= 0) {
        if (currentNumber.length() > 0) returnValue.add(currentNumber);
        currentNumber = "";
        returnValue.add("" + inputChar);
    } else if (inputChar != ' ') {
        System.out.println("Incorrect input symbol '"+inputChar+"'");
    }
}
if (currentNumber.length() > 0) returnValue.add(currentNumber);
```

Comment: Same issue with currentNumber += inputChar.

Comment: @DaveNewton, Fair point, I didn't want to be writing all his program for him. ;)

Comment: I've always thought homework answers should employ a buginator, just not sure how to work it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your `returnValue` is a `List<String>` but you are trying to add a `char` to the list. You can fix this by converting `inputChar` to a `String` when adding it to the list by using `String.valueOf(inputChar)`.

Comment: You can not cast a char to a String.